# How to launch an android app(not an activity) from the bottom of the screen to top?

Tags: java, android, transition, overridependingtransition

I have used 
`overridePendingTransition()`already but it is used to open an activity with the given transition not an app.

Moreover it works only when you are having an intent on clicking on a button, it won't work if use `overridePendingTransition()` in `onCreate()`

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Intent i = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up,R.anim.slide_out_up);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before setContentView use following code :

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.fade_out);
```

and in your finish() use following code :

```
@Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.slide_out_back_to_bottom);
    }
```

and create anim folder and put these files :

**slide_in_from_bottom:**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:zAdjustment="top">
    <translate
            android:duration="400"
            android:fromYDelta="100%p"
            android:toYDelta="0%p"
            >
    </translate>
    <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="0.8"
            android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="400"
            />
</set>
```

**slide_out_back_to_bottom:**

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:zAdjustment="top">
        <translate
                android:duration="400"
                android:fromYDelta="0%p"
                android:toYDelta="100%p"
                >
        </translate>
        <alpha
                android:fromAlpha="1.0"
                android:toAlpha="0.8"
                android:duration="400"
                />
    </set>
```

**fade_in:**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:zAdjustment="bottom">
    <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="0.0"
            android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="300"
            />
</set>
```

**fade_out:**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:zAdjustment="bottom">
    <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="1.0"
            android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="200"
            />
</set>
```

complete implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/AmirHadifar/AndroidTransition).

Comment: Are u sure it will work for launching the android app from bottom to top ?

Comment: Yes! I'm using this in one of my project too. also as you see I'm using Transition from 0% to 100% , this is exactly what you want. I also a bit fade_in/fade_out to be better.

Comment: is it correct :( if not can u share ur apk on drive or whereever

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        

    }
    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
    }


}`

Comment: i have wasted my 5 hours in finding the solution, but the app is not launching from the bottom please help

Comment: wait 5min to push it in Github :)

Comment: thanks mate but the mainactivity is not showing any transition :(

Comment: @user3542307 Yeah. I use transition for **DetailsActivity** you can apply same rule to **MainActivity**.